# Use Stripe with Card Swipe Reader

Tags: java, payment, credit-card, stripe-payments

Can stripe be used to accept payments via a card swipe reader. My concern is that the `cvc` would be required and I don't believe this data can be obtain from a card swipe.

So essentially the way this will work is, the customer will only swipe their card to pay for the service and is not required to input any data. Is this sufficient enough to use Stripe to process a payment without requiring the `cvc`.

Any feedback would be helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the CVC is not included on the stripe, and that's *precisely* why it exists -- to be a piece of information that must be read and entered manually and thus is not as vulnerable to theft. Think of it as equivalent to the PIN number on a bank card, except that it's less secret.

If you're interacting with systems which require the CVC, the stripe by itself is by definition helpful -- it saves entering some other data manually -- but not sufficient.

Comment: So essentially you are saying the `cvc` is not required and I can process a payment without the cvc?

Comment: Certainly some businesses do so, just as some are willing to accept a charge without a signature. Check with your processing company and/or bank to find out what additional risks you accept by operating in that less-secure mode... and whether they'll permit you to do it at all.